# Pandas group by custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

This should be really simple. What I want is the ability to group by the result of a function, just like in SQL you can group by an expresion:

```
SELECT substr(name, 1) as letter, COUNT(*) as count
FROM table
GROUP BY substr(name, 1)
```

This would count the number of rows where the name column starts with each letter of the alphabet.

I want to do the same in python, so I assumed I could pass in a function to groupby. However this only passes in the index column (the first column) to the function, for example 0, 1 or 2. What I want is the name column:

```
import pandas

# Return the first letter
def first_letter(row):

    # row is 0, then 1, then 2 etc.
    return row.name[0]

#Generate a data set of words
test = pandas.DataFrame({'name': ["benevolent", "hidden", "absurdity", "anonymous", "furious", "antidemocratic", "honeydew"]})

#              name
# 0      benevolent
# 1          hidden
# 2       absurdity
# 3       anonymous
# 4         furious
# 5  antidemocratic
# 6        honeydew

test.groupby(first_letter)
```

What am I doing wrong here. How can a group by something other than the row index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new column for the first letter:

```
def first_letter(row):
    return row[0]

test['first'] = test['name'].apply(first_letter)
```

and group it:

```
group = test.groupby('first')
```

use it:

```
>>> group.count()

     name
first      
a         3
b         1
f         1
h         2
```

Answer (score 4):

You generally want to use the vectorized `str` operators on string columns.  Use `get(0)` to extract the first letter, which is then used in the `groupby` operation.  Lastly, we take a `count` of the results.

Here is the link to the Pandas documentation for [working with text data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html).

Note that you can use regex patterns to `extract` more complicated expressions.

```
>>> test.groupby(test['name'].str.get(0))['name'].count()
name
a       3
b       1
f       1
h       2
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

More generically, your function should return the unique items in the dataframe on which to group implicitly together with its index.

For example, a function that rounds numbers can be used to group on the rounded number.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.25, 0.75, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8]})

>>> np.round(df.A)
0    0
1    1
2    3
3    3
4    3
Name: A, dtype: float64

>>> df.groupby(np.round(df.A)).mean()
      A
A      
0  0.25
1  0.75
3  2.70
```

A custom function should apply to a series of the dataframe, a boolean operator for example:

```
def ge_two(series):
    return series >= 2

>>> df.groupby(ge_two(df.A)).sum()
         A
A         
False  1.0
True   8.1
```

Comment: While that works for this example, my actual data isn't strings. What I'm looking for is a generic way to group by a function result

Comment: Thanks for the edits. This makes more sense. So in order to avoid adding a new column to the data frame, I can make a function that returns an array based on a series as you've done with ge_two

Comment: `np.round(df.A)` actually returns a series, which contains an index and the values returned from the function which will then be used for grouping.  In the accepted answer, the values of the function are stored back in the dataframe, which then does the alignment between the index and grouping values.

Comment: Yep that confirms what I thought. I actually like this answer more because it doesn't require a new series being added

Comment: The df.groupby(np.round(df.A)) was very helpful to me, thanks a lot!